# Writing to multiple tables from a form using a single model in joomla 3.0

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla3.0, custom-component

I am a joomla newbie and i have been trying to understand how to write to multiple tables in a single model, i read a few posts but their code seems to have been outdated as of joomla 2.5 or i am not being able to understand the actual implementation part, i am explaining my problem here.

I have a form that takes many values from the user and saves it in more than one table as this data belong to the other tables as well. But standard joomla scheme or the tutorials i had only allowed writing to a single table. Hence i would need to override some code and i don't know how. Please help me in this and i shall be providing here all the info to solve this problem that you guys might need. I have searched the internet enough only to find no place for joomla developers to actually solve this problem well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer for myself here although it needs correction a bit, but it solves this problem.

[Write to multiple tables in joomla component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738809/write-to-multiple-tables-in-joomla-component)